# Store does not have a valid reducer while the reducer is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am using the generator from https://github.com/stylesuxx/generator-react-webpack-redux. The development is going fine except that I have an error in browser console

`warning.js:10 Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.`

In `index.js` in reduces file, the code is stated below:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const reducers = {};
const combined = combineReducers(reducers);
module.exports = combined;
```

In `index.js` in stores file, the code is stated below:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from '../reducers';

function reduxStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(reducers, initialState,
    window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension());

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      // We need to require for hot reloading to work properly.
      const nextReducer = require('../reducers');  // eslint-disable-line global-require

      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}

export default reduxStore;
```

I am not using redux in current development but I use the generator for configuration there for future planning. Any idea how to make the reducer empty like the code above `const reducers = {};` without triggering any warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a valid reducer as the error suggest.
either you can try the following if you want to keep the boilerplate or

```
const reducers = { somename: () => {} };
const combined = combineReducers(reducers);
module.exports = combined;
```

or try

```
module.exports = () => {};
```

this will make sure a valid reducer function is returned. since you are not using redux this will not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to create a function instead of an empty object?

According to redux documentation it should be a function:

> reducer (Function): A reducing function that returns the next state tree, given the current state tree and an action to handle.
>   https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/createStore.md

Also I don't know if you need to use `combinereducers` as you only have one.